# Passing a const char* character string from unmanaged to managed

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, intptr

I have two communicating components - one managed, the other unmanaged. The managed needs to retrieve a character string from the unmanaged implementation (the same string or just a copy). I tried the following code.

```
// Unmanaged code
const char* GetTestName(Test* test)
{
    return test->getName();
}

// Managed wrapper
[DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint = "GetTestName")]
public static extern IntPtr GetTestName(IntPtr testObj);

// API Invocation
IntPtr testName = GetTestName(test);
string testStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(testName);
```

But, the value of testStr is not what is expected. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close but you have to use PtrToStringAnsi().  Auto uses the system default which will be Unicode.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. I actually tried all PtrToStringX() methods available. Am I doing something wrong in marshalling the data? The unmanaged unit is responsible for the character string memory.

Comment: No, your pinvoke declaration is correct.  I'd focus on making sure the *test* argument is correct.  Just debug this, turn on unmanaged debugging and set a breakpoint on test->getName().

Comment: Yup, got it. getName() is buggy. Thanks Hans.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this, instead:

```
[DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint = "EntryPoint")]
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern StringBuilder GetTestName(IntPtr testObj);
```

UnmanagedType.LPStr works with strings and System.Text.StringBuilder, and perhaps others (I only ever used those two).  I've found StringBuilder to work more consistantly, though.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for further information on the various string marshalling options.

Comment: Hah, and I added this as soon as you picked an answer.  Glad you got it figured out :)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Will check it out.